# Can a partition of a set contain uncountably many singletons?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $X=\left[ 0,1\right] $. I want to describe a set $A$ with the
following properties:

(i) Each element in $A$ is a subset of $X$,

(ii) Each element in $A$ is either an interval (e.g. $\left[ 0.2,0.4\right]
\in A$) or a singleton (e.g. $\left\{ 0.7\right\} \in A$),

(iii) The (potentially uncountable) union of the elements in $A$ is $X$,

(iv) Any two elements in $A$ are disjoint, with the only exception that if $%
a_{1}\in A$ and $a_{2}\in A$ are intervals then $a_{1}\cap a_{2}$ may
contain one element.

Is it correct to say that $A$ is a **partition** of $X$? My concern is that
since $A$ can potentially contain uncountably many singletons, there are measure/set
theoretic issues that I'm missing here.

Comment: $A=\{S \subset [0,1] : |S|=1\}$ is a partition of $[0,1]$ with uncountably many singletons. I don't really understand the concern you describe at the end. There's no reason that a family of sets, as you've specified, cannot contain uncountably many singletons.

Comment: "Can a partition of a set contain uncountably many singletons?" Sure, why not.  One very obvious partition is $A = \{\{x\}| x \in [0,1]\}$.  That is each and every set in the partition contains exactly *one* singleton.  (This is the *exact* same partition MathematicsStudent1121 described.)

Comment: My best guess is that you have some concept in your head that a partition should interact nicely with Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R$ (for instance, that the sum of the measures of the sets in the partition should equal the measure of the full set). But this isn't the case. A partition is a purely set-theoretic notion, its definition being properties (i), (iii), and (iv) in your post; in particular, it has nothing to do with measure theory. On the other hand, a measure is required to be countably additive but not necessarily uncountably additive, so there's no contradiction there either.

Comment: But note that one part of the definition of *partition* is that any two elements are either equal or disjoint. So your condition of two distinct elements having one point in common won't do.

Comment: No, A is not a partition.